# Fancybox change url

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I have a pinterest style gallery. I want to make it so when you click on the images it opens a fancybox with a larger image and then comments and other stuff below it in a box. But I want each image/ image fancybox to have it's own url so people can share the links and stuff. Any Ideas on how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use fancybox as default. When the onComplete event is raised, manipulate the DOM and serach for the fancybox container and just append the comments and stuff.

Comment: what do you mean by use fancybox as default?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url in the browser with HTML5 history.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

And then on full page load you can get the url with window.location and modify the DOM to fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

There are kinda two ways: 
1. like Facebook does: http://spoiledmilk.dk/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page 
2. like Twitter does: 
you can access and change the #-part of url using `location.hash` 
    `//example.com/`
    `location.hash = 'foo'; //becomes example.com/#foo`

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this by creating a PHP script that takes in the id of the image e.g. `outputimage.php?id=123` and then outputs the html of the image, comments etx. This script could be called with a jQuery ajax call that requests the html from the script and then places it in the fancybox div.

Another page called `image.php?id=` that again takes in the id of the image and uses `outputimage.php` to display the html in a separate page layout. This page would then be your standalone layout.